# Android: Actionbar item onclick

Tags: android, android-actionbar

1-To add a search item to my **[actionbar](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)** i have the item in this way:

```
<item 

      android:id="@+id/search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search" 
      android:title="@string/Search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"    
      />
```

//onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

//OnOptionItemSelected

```
public boolean OnOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {

      case R.id.search:
          action_search();
          return true;  

      default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }   
}
```

//Search_Action

```
public void action_search()
    {

        System.out.println("Heeeeey");

    }
```

,but if i add this one `android:onClick="action_search"` it gives me these errors

```
03-20 07:40:12.622: E/Trace(1277): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler action_search in class com.example.lesson1.MainActivity
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:217)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:417)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.example.lesson1.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:30)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: action_search [interface android.view.MenuItem]
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(MenuInflater.java:215)
03-20 07:40:13.002: E/AndroidRuntime(1277):     ... 18 more
```

2-What is `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`? What is it doing?

Comment: please post your oncreateoptionmeu()  implementation

Comment: Your `Activity` should contain this method `public void action_search(MenuItem menuItem) {}`...

Comment: @GopalRao i edite the question plz review it

Comment: @MSS i edite the question plz review it

Comment: do you want to use searchview widget or custom widget ?? pls post entire implementation  , so that i will make correction

Comment: @MSS plz review it again i added all nesseary things

Comment: Your `action_search()` method should have `MenuItem` as a parameter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** You shouldn't add onClicks to ActionMenu items that way. Instead, you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.search:
        // your action goes here
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And inflate your layout into the ActionBar as the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**2.** `ifRoom` means place the action item on the action bar if there is space. However, space is determined by the following: less than half the width of the action bar horizontal space and the count is less than the max number of action items - Jake Wharton.

[Have a look here for more information on the android ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

Answer (score 2):

The way to process action bar clicks in your `Activity` is as following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (R.id.search == id) {
        // do something and maybe return true...
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The `ifRoom` tag means that if there's not enough room for the item in the action bar, it will appear in the action overflow.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Now just run it and check if it really works. ;)

Comment: Sitll  not working. and i edited my question again plz take a look again

Comment: What exactly is not working? Have you updated your stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

ActionBar Menu items are created using

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

And then the click events of the items are delivered using

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.search:
        //TODO do your thing.
        return true;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}
```

One more thing, 
ifRoom means that the item is displayed as an icon if there is room. If you have only one item, there is a room always. If there is not room, the item is displayed in overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the complete tutorial as mentioned in that [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)

and **ifRoom** tag means: the specified item will be visible only if there is space available on the action bar.

And **dont use onClick** listener in this senario, **onOptionItemSelected** will be perfect. Its all well documented in the mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `Activity` click of menu item will be handeled here.
   .

@Override

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 // Handle presses on the action bar items

       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.search:
           //do your work here
           return true;    
            }
        }
```

2.
`android:showAsAction`

Keyword. When and how this item should appear as an action item in the Action Bar. A menu item can appear as an action item only when the activity includes an ActionBar

`ifRoom`
Only place this item in the Action Bar if there is room for it.

you can get details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android version 11 and above , you can use android searchview widget in your activity  like below,

**main.xml**

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search_title"/>
  </menu>
```

and ,

**onCreateOptionsMenu()**

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch)
            .getActionView();

}
```