# Make an android activity full screen over a button

Tags: android, android-activity, fullscreen

Im new on android development and I want to know how can I make an android activity fullscreen via a Icon placed on toolbar.

Thank You.

Please click on link for example image:
[Click to preview example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udJRl.jpg)

Comment: have you read the android documentation thoroughly? there is a fullscreen activity option already in android studio...

Answer (score 1):

I think this previous post may give you what you are looking for:

[Fullscreen Activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android)

**From post mentioned above:**

You can do it programatically:

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

**How your code should differ:**

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    Button x = findViewById(R.id.yourButton);
       x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
          }
       });
}
}
```

This would link your button with this code.

Comment: it is posible with this code but not in onCreate...if he put new private void onFullScreenPressed () { .....this code.... }, otherwise it will be fullscreen at start without pressing button

Comment: If you think an answer to another question solves this issue as well then consider flagging the post as a duplicate rather than reposting the answer here.

Comment: I tried your method Alexander N. but its not working. My app crash when I click button from menu bar.

Comment: @user3664679 - What does your code look like for the onClickListener of your menu bar button?  Can you post the error message from logcat?

Comment: Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen);
        assert x != null;
        x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatica);
            }
        });    and error is

Comment: @user3664679 - Since it is coming from a toolbar, you would want to wire it for the actionbar.  See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526498/android-actionbar-item-onclick

Comment: So it sould be something like this: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.fullscreen) {
           // startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactUS.class));
            supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        }
        }

Comment: Something like this: `@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.fullscreen:
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}`

Comment: Now i got  this error: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Window feature must be requested before adding content